# Sync takes forever?

Tags: synchronization

I set up a Monero wallet using the GUI version. I'm on a 2016 MBP and 24 hours have gone by now. Checked this morning and say 870 blocks remaining... Now it's showing 1180921 blocks remaining.

Checking the deamon log I see lots of errors:

```
2017-08-24 10:35:19.265     INFO    global  
contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
Height: 1383518/1383518 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 157.70 MH/s, v5, up to date, 9(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 25m 39s
```

Why does this take so long? If this is the case most of the time, bye bye Monero :)

Comment: It looks fully synced, and does not show errors ?

Answer (score 1):

Got into settings and added --block-sync-size 20 as deamon start up flag, which increased speed drastically - wallet is now sync and balance showing.

Comment: With the new v0.11.0.0 release the block-sync-size issue has now been optiminzed by default